# How can I manually control dependencies using SmartAssembly?

Tags: redgate, smartassembly

I have several libraries that I want to obfuscate and embed using RedGate's SmartAssembly. However, SmartAssembly's UI is bizarre since it only lets me embed dependencies that it identifies. In my scenario, I have some dependencies that aren't directly linked, and thus SmartAssembly is ignoring them.

Is there a way to get SmartAssembly to include any assemblies I want, as opposed to just the assemblies that its scan identifies?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

SmartAssembly only lets you embed assemblies it can detect, ie assemblies that are directly referenced in the metadata of the assembly you are protecting, or one of its' dependencies. For assemblies that are late-bound, your only option is to include the assembly separately in your distribution.

Comment: Unfortunately, that's what my research found as well.